Matrices de transformación homogénea con python
Estoy haciendo MTH con Python, estoy usando NumPy para hacer mis matrices el problema que tengo es que no puedo representar de manera correcta la matriz que debe salir. La salida se debería ver así:

pero la salida que tengo es la siguiente:

tuve que modificar el valor de ese parámetro ya que no deja operar y quería saber si hay alguna forma de lograr que las variables se vean representadas ya de perdida solo "q".
Aquí mi función:
def rotq(q1):
    if isinstance(q1, str):  
        q1 = 1  
    cos=round(np.radians(np.cos(q1)))
    sen=round((np.sin(q1)))
    rotZt = np.array([[cos, -sen, 0, 0],
                       [sen, cos, 0, 0],
                       [0, 0, 1, 0],
                       [0, 0, 0, 1]])
    return rotZt

A0 = rotq("q1")


Si quieres usar matemáticas simbólicas NumPy (por si solo) no es lo más adecuado, hay bibliotecas específicas para ello, una de las más conocidas es SymPy.
Por ejemplo:
from pprint import pprint
from sympy import cos, sin, Symbol, Matrix

q = Symbol("q")

matriz = Matrix([
    [cos(q), -sin(q), 0, 0],
    [sin(q), cos(q),  0, 0],
    [     0,      0,  1, 0],
    [     0,      0,  0, 1]
    ]),

pprint(matriz)

La salida es:
Matrix([
[cos(q), -sin(q), 0, 0],
[sin(q),  cos(q), 0, 0],
[     0,       0, 1, 0],
[     0,       0, 0, 1]])

Puedes operar sobre la matriz con funciones propias de SymPy junto a NumPy, SciPy...
>>> matriz.transpose()
Matrix([
[ cos(q), sin(q), 0, 0],
[-sin(q), cos(q), 0, 0],
[      0,      0, 1, 0],
[      0,      0, 0, 1]])

>>> matriz.subs({"q": 1})
Matrix([
[cos(1), -sin(1), 0, 0],
[sin(1),  cos(1), 0, 0],
[     0,       0, 1, 0],
[     0,       0, 0, 1]])


Muchísimas gracias, una pregunta rápida ¿Si le paso como parámetro un entero debo remover Symbol para poder operar los senos y cosenos normalmente verdad?

Efectivamente, o puedes usar subs() como en el ejemplo final, lo que te permite reutilizar la matriz original: matriz_q1 = matriz.subs({"q": 1})
